# How to iterate over a list and append all the results to an array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to extract the values from "all", for which the first columns is 0 or 1.

```
arr = np.zeros((0,2))
for num in [0,1]:
    spike = np.vstack((arr, all[all[:,0] == num] ))
print(spike)
```

When i print "spike" only the values of 1 are present.

Comment: what is all? I am assuming you are using it to store some values, but in python 'all' is a built-in function, so you should be getting a Type Error first.

Comment: Yes all is where all the values are stored!

Comment: try not to use reserved words as variable names.

Comment: maybe you share your whole code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the value of `spike` within the loop.

Comment: Ok i understand, but how do i not overwrite it?

Comment: because if i print within the loop i get the right results, but i can't figure out how to do it correctly

Comment: Every time your code executes `spike = ` it overwrites the old value of `spike`. If you define it outside of the loop and only append to it, you'll be fine. In fact, you do not need `spike` at all, you can just do `arr = np.vstack(arr, ...)` within the loop, this takes the old `arr` value and appends something to it.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer.